# Why Laravel post method doesn't work on router page?

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am a beginner at Laravel and I try to deal with this situation. My router doesn't work when I use the post method. I clear my cache, view but still don't work. I watch so many YouTubers and still, the same issue goes on. Thanks for all your help.

**Error:**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

web.php

```
    Route::get('/mainpage', function () {
        return view('general');
    });

    Route::post('/general','App\Http\Controllers\GeneralController@store');
```

GeneralController.php

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        echo"works";
        dd($request);   
    }
```

general.blade.php

```
    <form action="{{url('/general')}}" method="POST" >
        @csrf              
        <label for="email" class="u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-1">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="" id="email" name="email" class="u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
        
        <label for="name" class="u-label u-text-body-alt-color u-label-2">name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="" id="password" name="password" class="u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required="">
                                    
        <a href="{{url('/general')}}" >Submit</a>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-form-control-hidden">
    </form>
```

Comment: try this `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Thanks, I did some cleaning before ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with laravel, it is a problem with html. In your code, if someone clicks the anchor tag, because of the href link, the window will open a url called /general. But this will not submit your form, it will simply open another page.

```
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Just let the form be submitted normally and everthing should work fine.

Edit:

Something general, it is better if you name your route, for example:

```
Route::post('/general','App\Http\Controllers\GeneralController@store')->name('general');
```

And then you can simply access the url/route in your view like this: 
`<form action="{{route('general')}}" method="POST">`